# Display Notice on product page after Review Submit in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I am using the code below to "re-direct" back to the product page because if not, the page stays at the "bottom" where the review form is.

My question is this:
how do I print / display a message on the product page after the review has been submitted by the customer?

Here's my code:

```
    add_filter('comment_post_redirect', 'redirect_after_comment');
    function redirect_after_comment($location) {
    $location = wp_get_referer();
wc_add_notice( __( 'Thank you for writing a review. Use this coupon code <code>FIVEOFF</code> on the checkout and get $5 OFF!', 'woocommerce' ), 'success' );
    return $location;
    }
```

Problem is, the message is not being displayed and I tried adding in a `do_action` for `wc_notice` which did not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `wc_add_notice()` before `return $location;`. Because `return` stops the execution of the function and sends the value back, so the statements after it won't be executed.